# How do i fix this "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'" Error?

Tags: python, csv, oop, typeerror

I am currently following this tutorial about Object Oriented Programming but even though i followed all the steps i can't seem to find a solutions as to why my code gets this error and i have no clue what this error means, here's the vid to compare if needed: [text](https://youtu.be/Ej_02ICOIgs?t=3655)

[I keep getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaUIF.png)

here's my code:

```
import csv

class Item:
    pay_rate = 0.8 #the pay rate after 20% discount
    all = []
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity = 0):
        #Run validations to the received arguments
        assert price >= 0, f"Price {price} is not greater than or equal to zero!"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"Quantity {quantity} is not greater than or equal to zero"
        
        #assign to self object
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
        
        #Actions to execute
        Item.all.append(self)

    def calculate_total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
    
    def apply_discount(self):
        self.price = self.price * self.pay_rate

    @classmethod
    def instantiate_from_csv(cls):
        with open('items.csv', 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            items = list(reader)

        for item in items:
            Item(
                name=item.get('name'),
                price=int(item.get('price')),
                quantity=int(item.get('quantity')),
            )

        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item('{self.name}', '{self.price}', '{self.quantity}')"

Item.instantiate_from_csv()
print(Item.all)
```

and this is what my csv looks like:

```
name, price, quantity
"Phone", 100, 1
"Laptop", 1000, 3
"Cable", 10, 5
"Mouse", 50, 5
"Keyboard", 75, 5
```

I am still a beginner so i don't know where to start and couldn't find any solutions online.

Comment: Please post code, data, and **results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV file has space after the comma delimiters, and that's being treated as a literal part of the field name, so the dictionary key is `' price'`.

You can tell `csv.DictReader` to ignore these spaces by using the `skipinitialspace` option.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the spaces in the csv file header:

```
name, price, quantity
```

Because of the spaces, the middle column name is treated as `" price"`, not `"price"`, and therefore `item.get('price')` did not find any matching value and so it returned `None`.

Take out the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional space in the field " price", try this one

```
    @classmethod
    def instantiate_from_csv(cls):
        with open('items.csv', 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            items = list(reader)
            print(items)

        for item in items:
            Item(
                name=item.get('name'),
                price=int(item.get(' price')),
                quantity=int(item.get(' quantity')),
            )
```